# What is the most elegant way to do an Excel VBA SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm using this code and very similar others that **are working perfectly** but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it:
(Extract)

```vb
Erase ArrUserMetRecCentros
Cnn.Open
CnnQry = _
    "SELECT" & _
    "   APP_METERS_Q_Profiles.ProfileId, " & _
    "   Main_Profile_Info.FieldValue, " & _
    "   APP_METERS_T_Access.[Read], " & _
    "   APP_METERS_T_Access.Write " & _
    "FROM (APP_METERS_Q_Profiles " & _
    "   INNER JOIN Main_Profile_Info ON APP_METERS_Q_Profiles.ProfileId = Main_Profile_Info.ProfileId) " & _
    "   INNER JOIN APP_METERS_T_Access ON APP_METERS_Q_Profiles.ProfileId = APP_METERS_T_Access.APPMETERSQProfileId " & _
    "WHERE " & _
    "   (((Main_Profile_Info.FieldId)=1) AND " & _
    "   ((APP_METERS_T_Access.APPMETERSQUserId)=1) AND " & _
    "   ((APP_METERS_T_Access.APPMETERSTDataTypeId)=1) AND " & _
    "   ((APP_METERS_T_Access.[Read])=-1));"
Set rst = Cnn.Execute(CnnQry)
    With rst
        x = x + 1
        Do Until rst.EOF
            For i = 1 To 4
                ArrUserMetRecCentros(x, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Value
            Next i
            .MoveNext
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        ArrUserMetRecCentros(0, 0) = x - 1
    End With
Cnn.Close
```

This connects to a MS SQL EXPRESS server and stores the requested data in an array that I'm going to use in EXCEL.
I'm not looking for you to rewrite my code (it's my job ;)) just few tips if there's any. Things like "Not to use 'Set rst= *blablabla*' better option is to do *'this'*. Or "define all your queries in different public string variables to keep code cleaner", etc.

Thank you very much for any help received.
Gustavo.

Comment: This is likely to get closed for being opinion based but I think your VBA code is fine. I would prefer to have my query as a stored procedure instead but that is preference.

Comment: This looks fine but I'd do my best to construct a function which takes in a SQL string and returns an array of results: no need to repeat this logic multiple times.  Same goes for any DB operations - creating a class to manage the interfacing is a useful investment of time.  Since you're in Excel you could consider storing your SQL on a worksheet instead of in your VBA.  Also in your `With rst` block you still have a couple of unneeded `rst`

Comment: Sean Lange .- Thx. Stored Precedures are on my mind. When I finish the APP will think about what to move to Stored Procedures. i.e. in my code the tables with __Q__ in the name are Views at the server.
Tim Williams .- Thx about rst repeated. Fixed it at code.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
CnnQry = _
    "SELECT" & _
    "   APP_METERS_Q_Profiles.ProfileId, " & _
    "   Main_Profile_Info.FieldValue, " & _
    "   APP_METERS_T_Access.[Read], " & _
    "   APP_METERS_T_Access.Write " & _
    "FROM (APP_METERS_Q_Profiles " & _
    "   INNER JOIN Main_Profile_Info ON APP_METERS_Q_Profiles.ProfileId = Main_Profile_Info.ProfileId) " & _
    "   INNER JOIN APP_METERS_T_Access ON APP_METERS_Q_Profiles.ProfileId = APP_METERS_T_Access.APPMETERSQProfileId " & _
    "WHERE " & _
    "   (((Main_Profile_Info.FieldId)=1) AND " & _
    "   ((APP_METERS_T_Access.APPMETERSQUserId)=1) AND " & _
    "   ((APP_METERS_T_Access.APPMETERSTDataTypeId)=1) AND " & _
    "   ((APP_METERS_T_Access.[Read])=-1));"
```

That doesn't belong in code. It's a gigantic string literal: you get no syntax highlighting, no validation, no intellisense; you need to track parentheses manually, and beyond 20 or so line continuations, it stops compiling and you start doing things like `CnnQry = CnnQty & "...some more inline SQL..."`

If it needed parameter values, they'd probably be just concatenated in - and then you'd need to care for single quotes, and poof you have a *SQL Injection* vulnerability that's not only a serious security issue, but also a bug, no less.

Inline SQL is an abomination, regardless of what language it's done in. The less you have, the better.

For what it's worth I make a typo every single time I try to type `CnnQry`: vowels are permitted, and there's nothing wrong with using `sql` either.

You want SQL queries on the SQL Server side, not in your code.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GiveMeAGoodName
AS BEGIN
    SELECT
       ...
    FROM ...
        INNER JOIN ...
        INNER JOIN ...
    WHERE ...
END
```

And now your inline SQL in VBA becomes:

```vb
Const sql As String = "dbo.GiveMeAGoodName"
```

And the VBA code should use a `Command` to get the `Recordset`:

```vb
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cnn
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.CommantType = adCmdStoredProc

'add parameters if needed:
'cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(...)

Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
Set results = cmd.Execute
```

Note that with proper parameterization as above, you're letting SQL Server do its job and deal with quoting, and [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) can't do any harm.

Use `Range.CopyFromRecordset` to dump a recordset onto a `Range` without looping.

Comment: What else I can say than 'I love you'. Thank you very much for your time, I'll follow your recommendations. No rep. enough to vote this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to lack of rep.

Rather than loop your recordset at the 'With' Statement; I'd just add the recordset as a whole to the spreadsheet.

```
Set rst = Cnn.Execute(CnnQry)
If rst.EOF Then
   'Catching empty recordsets
Else
   Worksheets("Today").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End If
Cnn.Close
```

To advise. We use an ADODB Connection and Recordset objects. Your code looks like you do this also.

Comment: This is more than just a comment. And is a good improvement. +1 from me.

Comment: Cheers @SeanLange !

Answer (score 0):

You could look at just using the array from `.GetRows` method of the recordset object

see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15

You can add the `where`s to your join also, like `customers join orders on (customers.id=orders.id AND order.value>100)`